# SQL Case Expression Syntax?

Tags: sql

What is the **complete** and correct syntax for the SQL Case expression?

Comment: `case expression` is the correct term as they evaluate to a scalar value (also. in SQL a `statement` is terminated by the "statement terminator" which is the semi-colon).

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The **complete** syntax depends on the database engine you're working with:

For SQL Server:

```
CASE case-expression
    WHEN when-expression-1 THEN value-1
  [ WHEN when-expression-n THEN value-n ... ]
  [ ELSE else-value ]
END
```

or:

```
CASE
    WHEN boolean-when-expression-1 THEN value-1
  [ WHEN boolean-when-expression-n THEN value-n ... ]
  [ ELSE else-value ]
END
```

expressions, etc:

```
case-expression    - something that produces a value
when-expression-x  - something that is compared against the case-expression
value-1            - the result of the CASE statement if:
                         the when-expression == case-expression
                      OR the boolean-when-expression == TRUE
boolean-when-exp.. - something that produces a TRUE/FALSE answer
```

Link: [CASE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Also note that the ordering of the WHEN statements is important. You can easily write multiple WHEN clauses that overlap, and **the first one that matches is used**.

**Note**: If no ELSE clause is specified, and no matching WHEN-condition is found, the value of the CASE expression will be *NULL*.

Comment: has this always been a SQL thing? I've only just recently discovered this

Answer (score 21):

Considering you tagged multiple products, I'd say the *full* correct syntax would be the one found in the ISO/ANSI SQL-92 standard:

```
<case expression> ::=
       <case abbreviation>
     | <case specification>

<case abbreviation> ::=
       NULLIF <left paren> <value expression> <comma>
              <value expression> <right paren>
     | COALESCE <left paren> <value expression>
                { <comma> <value expression> }... <right paren>

<case specification> ::=
       <simple case>
     | <searched case>

<simple case> ::=
     CASE <case operand>
          <simple when clause>...
        [ <else clause> ]
     END

<searched case> ::=
     CASE
       <searched when clause>...
     [ <else clause> ]
     END

<simple when clause> ::= WHEN <when operand> THEN <result>

<searched when clause> ::= WHEN <search condition> THEN <result>

<else clause> ::= ELSE <result>

<case operand> ::= <value expression>

<when operand> ::= <value expression>

<result> ::= <result expression> | NULL

<result expression> ::= <value expression>
```

Syntax Rules

```
1) NULLIF (V1, V2) is equivalent to the following <case specification>:

     CASE WHEN V1=V2 THEN NULL ELSE V1 END

2) COALESCE (V1, V2) is equivalent to the following <case specification>:

     CASE WHEN V1 IS NOT NULL THEN V1 ELSE V2 END

3) COALESCE (V1, V2, . . . ,n ), for n >= 3, is equivalent to the
   following <case specification>:

     CASE WHEN V1 IS NOT NULL THEN V1 ELSE COALESCE (V2, . . . ,n )
     END

4) If a <case specification> specifies a <simple case>, then let CO
   be the <case operand>:

   a) The data type of each <when operand> WO shall be comparable
      with the data type of the <case operand>.

   b) The <case specification> is equivalent to a <searched case>
      in which each <searched when clause> specifies a <search
      condition> of the form "CO=WO".

5) At least one <result> in a <case specification> shall specify a
   <result expression>.

6) If an <else clause> is not specified, then ELSE NULL is im-
   plicit.

7) The data type of a <case specification> is determined by ap-
   plying Subclause 9.3, "Set operation result data types", to the
   data types of all <result expression>s in the <case specifica-
   tion>.

Access Rules

   None.

General Rules

1) Case:

   a) If a <result> specifies NULL, then its value is the null
      value.

   b) If a <result> specifies a <value expression>, then its value
      is the value of that <value expression>.

2) Case:

   a) If the <search condition> of some <searched when clause> in
      a <case specification> is true, then the value of the <case
      specification> is the value of the <result> of the first
      (leftmost) <searched when clause> whose <search condition> is
      true, cast as the data type of the <case specification>.

   b) If no <search condition> in a <case specification> is true,
      then the value of the <case expression> is the value of the
      <result> of the explicit or implicit <else clause>, cast as
      the data type of the <case specification>.
```

Comment: The only one who tried to address the universal syntax requirement!

Answer (score 19):

Here are the [`CASE` statement examples from the PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html) (Postgres follows the SQL standard here):

```
SELECT a,
   CASE WHEN a=1 THEN 'one'
        WHEN a=2 THEN 'two'
        ELSE 'other'
   END
FROM test;
```

or

```
SELECT a,
   CASE a WHEN 1 THEN 'one'
          WHEN 2 THEN 'two'
          ELSE 'other'
   END
FROM test;
```

Obviously the second form is cleaner when you are just checking one field against a list of possible values. The first form allows more complicated expressions.

Comment: The title of the link given above, for section 9.18 is "Conditional Expressions", then 9.18.1 refers to "Case" i.e. **case expression** is the correct term

Answer (score 9):

Sybase has the same [case syntax](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks115.htm) as SQL Server:

### Description

Supports conditional SQL expressions; can be used anywhere a value expression can be used.

#### Syntax

```
case 
     when search_condition then expression 
    [when search_condition then expression]...
    [else expression]
end
```

#### Case and values syntax

```
case expression
     when expression then expression 
    [when expression then expression]...
    [else expression]
end
```

### Parameters

#### case

begins the case expression.

#### when

precedes the search condition or the expression to be compared.

#### search_condition

is used to set conditions for the results that are selected. Search conditions for case expressions are similar to the search conditions in a where clause. Search conditions are detailed in the Transact-SQL User’s Guide.

#### then

precedes the expression that specifies a result value of case.

#### expression

is a column name, a constant, a function, a subquery, or any combination of column names, constants, and functions connected by arithmetic or bitwise operators. For more information about expressions, see “Expressions” in.

### Example

```
select disaster, 
       case
            when disaster = "earthquake" 
                then "stand in doorway"
            when disaster = "nuclear apocalypse" 
                then "hide in basement"
            when monster = "zombie apocalypse" 
                then "hide with Chuck Norris"
            else
                then "ask mom"
       end 
  from endoftheworld
```

Answer (score 4):

Oracle [syntax from the 11g Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/expressions004.htm#SQLRF20037):

```
CASE { simple_case_expression | searched_case_expression }
     [ else_clause ]
     END
```

*simple_case_expression*

```
expr { WHEN comparison_expr THEN return_expr }...
```

*searched_case_expression*

```
{ WHEN condition THEN return_expr }...
```

*else_clause*

```
ELSE else_expr
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you can find a complete guide for [MySQL case statements in SQL](https://geekposting.com/case-statements-in-sql-complete-guide/).

```
CASE
     WHEN some_condition THEN return_some_value
     ELSE return_some_other_value
END
```

Answer (score -2):

Case statement syntax in SQL SERVER:

```
CASE column
   WHEN value1 THEN 1
   WHEN value3 THEN 2
   WHEN value3 THEN 3
   WHEN value1 THEN 4
   ELSE ''
END
```

And we can use like below also:

```
CASE 
   WHEN column=value1 THEN 1
   WHEN column=value3 THEN 2
   WHEN column=value3 THEN 3
   WHEN column=value1 THEN 4
   ELSE ''
END
```

Comment: **case expression** is the correct term