# How do you return a constant from an sql statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

How do I return a constant from an sql statement?

For example how would I change the code below so "my message" would return if my (boolean expression) was true

```
if (my boolean expression)
 "my message"
else
 select top 1 name from people;
```

I am using ms sql 2000

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Did you try:

```
select 'my message';
```

Comment: You might want to include a field name to match the else condition.

Comment: This seems to omit the condition?

Answer (score 11):

```
select "my message" as message
```

Comment: The question wasn't how to do it conditionally.  :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't have MSSQL handy, but check the syntax for the CASE statement in case I got it wrong and also I'm not sure if the TOP 1 should go outside the case as I put it here or if it should go inside (ELSE TOP 1 name). The idea is:

```
SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN myexpression = 'true' THEN 'my message' ELSE name END
FROM people;
```

Here myexpression has to be either constants or related to the tables present in the query, for example

```
CASE WHEN address LIKE '%Michigan%'
```

where address is another field in the table people.

PS: Found the MSSQL CASE syntax [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622/sql-case-statement-syntax) :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
select top 1 name 
from people
where @MyParameter = whatever

union

select 'my message' as name
where @MyParameter != whatever
```

All in one statement.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this on the AdventureWorks database and it works

```
Use AdventureWorks

Declare @myVar int
SET @myVar = 1

if (@myVar = 2)

     select top 2 * from HumanResources.Department

else

     select top 1 * from HumanResources.Department
```