# SQL Decode statement

Tags: sql, decode

I am trying to use a SQL Decode statement to Decode (D.code ,2,'Resident',else,'Business') Description,  Is there a way to identify everything else in a decode statement?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using oracle since DECODE isn't an ansi sql statement as far as I know. Also, I don't really understand the question.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212059/standard-sql-alternative-to-oracle-decode

Answer (score 2):

yes, there is:

```
decode ( <condition>, <test expr #1>, <result #1>, ..., <test expr #n>, <result #n>, <fallback result>);
```

however, in standard sql you would use

```
case <condition>
    when <test expr #1> then <result #1>
    ...
    when <test expr #n> then <result #n>
    else                     <fallback result>
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the basic syntax correct except you don't use the 'else' in a DECODE function.
Inside the parentheses is first the thing to decode, then the code/description pairs, then finally, the optional default (else) value.

Here is a sample of one that I use:

```
DECODE(status,'A','Approved','D','Declined','I','Counter Offer','Other')
```

Good luck,

Marvin