# Spring Data using sort not at the end

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Can I give sort parameter not at the end expresion? Because i need use sort parameter inside over() function.

example:

```
@Query(value = "...?2...over(?4)...?1...?3")
myMethod(int a,int b,int c,Sort sort);
```

or expression for sort inside over:  ,--#sort\n , #{#sort} ..

I still get :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.Integer ...name of method.. (int,int,int,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort)!

Comment: Did you read the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.sorting)? Can you post a [mcve] and complete stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters of type `Sort` get special treatment by Spring Data JPA.

Even if that wouldn't be the case what you try to achieve can't be accomplished with a simple bind parameter, because bind parameters allowed in these places by SQL.

Depending on what you want to achieve you might be able to do something like the following:

```
@Query("select .... over(... order by CASE ?1 WHEN "first THEN first
     WHEN 'last' THEN last
     END")
public Something method(String columnNameForSorting)
```

assuming you have the columns `first` and `last` you want to switch between for sorting.

[Standard SQL alternative to Oracle DECODE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212059/standard-sql-alternative-to-oracle-decode) for more information about the CASE expression

Comment: For direct completion string into like (order by ?4) into to the sql, sql returned bad result. But if I tried this way, as you wrote, it was good. Thanks!

Comment: If this solves the problem please accept it (click the checkmark) and upvote it. Especially the checkmark makes it obvious to others finding the question what solves the problem.