# SQL SELECT : map columns to new column

Tags: sql, select, dictionary, new-operator

I have a table with two columns of integers. I would like to select data from it (in some standard way) and add a new column by rule:

- if number on left is bigger, new column is 1
- if number on left is smaller, new column is -1
- if numbers are equal, new column is 0

Example:

```
16 | 15 | 1
20 | 28 |-1
11 | 11 | 0
28 | 14 | 1
...
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT X,Y,
    CASE WHEN X > Y THEN 1
         WHEN X < Y THEN -1
         ELSE 0 END AS "Z"
FROM table_name
```

Comment: Is this "CASE" in standard? I was thinking about joining with (SELECT -1/0/1) ON (one of 3 conditions) and grouping it somehow...

Comment: Yes, it is standard SQL. See the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622/sql-case-statement-syntax).

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you want the `SIGN` Function

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, SIGN(Col1 - Col2) AS Col3
FROM   T
```