# Multiple AS Statements From a Single Column

Tags: sql

I'm fairly new at `SQL` and have run into an issue that has me stumped. It's easier to just explain what I'm trying to do. I have a table that has a column `t.number` that contains either a 4, a 6 or something uninteresting to me. It corresponds with a a text field, `t.text`. Here's the pseudo code of what I want to do:

```
if (t.number == 4)
   t.text as ImAFour
else if (t.number == 6)
   t.text as ImASix
```

Everything I try to write ends up with double entries or overwriting. Any ideas?

Comment: See the following post on the SQL CASE statement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622/sql-case-statement-syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
SELECT
    CASE t.number WHEN 4 THEN t.text ELSE '' END AS ImAFour,
    CASE t.number WHEN 6 THEN t.text ELSE '' END as ImASix,
    ....
FROM table t
```

The exact syntax will depend on your RDBMS, which was not tagged in the original question.

Comment: Excellent that looks good, now again excuse my lack of experience, but can I just embed this select statement into my main select statement? I didn't mention but there are some other fields being pulled as well, but I've tried a version of that and it led to duplicates. Would I do:

    SELECT
       t.1, t.2,
       SELECT
          'Your Code'?

Comment: Something like `SELECT field1, field2, ... CASE t.number WHEN 4 THEN t.text ELSE '' END AS ImAFour, CASE t.number WHEN 6 THEN t.text ELSE '' END as ImASix ... FROM table t ...` Each case statement becomes a seperate column/field in the query result set.