# Ifelse statement in R with multiple conditions

Tags: r, if-statement

With the following sample data I'm trying to create a new variable "Den" (value "0" or "1") based on the values of three conditional variables (Denial1, Denial2, and Denial3).

I want a "0" if ANY of the three conditional variables has a "0" and a "1" only if EACH conditional variable that has a value in it has a value of "1" (e.g., isn't NA).

```
structure(list(Denial1 = NA_real_, Denial2 = 1, Denial3 = NA_real_, 
Den = NA), .Names = c("Denial1", "Denial2", "Denial3", "Den"
), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
```

I've tried both of the following commands that result in a missing value NA for "Den":

```
DF$Den<-ifelse (DF$Denial1 < 1 | DF$Denial2 < 1 | DF$Denial3 < 1, "0", "1")

DF$Den<-ifelse(DF$Denial1 < 1,"0", ifelse (DF$Denial2 < 1,"0", ifelse(DF$Denial3 < 1,"0", "1")))
```

Could someone demonstrate how to do this?

Comment: possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012222/nested-ifelse-statement-in-r?rq=1

Comment: @jaimedash thank you for the link, I did read that before I posted the question and included the script for nested ifelse statements above. I must still be making an error somewhere.

Comment: you need both 1) not `NA` and 2) `< 1`. It's ugly, but chaining several of these `(DF$Denial1 < 1 & !is.na(DF$Denial1) )` with `&` should work. (Edited to change from `&&` to elementwise `&`)

Comment: @jaimedash Many thanks that works and it's ugly!

Comment: awesome. you should post the working ugliness as an answer

Comment: Is your question worded incorrectly? You say you want a 1 'only if EACH conditional variable that has a value in it has a value of "1" (e.g., isn't NA)'. Doesn't this mean *all* of the values need to be 1 in order for *Den* to be 1? However, your answer (and apparently what you really want) is for *Den* to be 1 if *any* of *Denial1*, *Denial2*, or *Denial3* are 1.

Answer (score 33):

Based on suggestions from @jaimedash and @Old_Mortality I found a solution:

```
DF$Den <- ifelse(DF$Denial1 < 1 & !is.na(DF$Denial1) | DF$Denial2 < 1 &  
!is.na(DF$Denial2) | DF$Denial3 < 1 & !is.na(DF$Denial3), "0", "1")
```

Then to ensure a value of NA if all values of the conditional variables are NA:

```
DF$Den <- ifelse(is.na(DF$Denial1) & is.na(DF$Denial2) & is.na(DF$Denial3), 
NA, DF$Den)
```

Answer (score 8):

How about?

```
DF$Den<-ifelse (is.na(DF$Denial1) | is.na(DF$Denial2) | is.na(DF$Denial3), "0", "1")
```

Comment: I'll try to clarify: I don't want a "0" if the value for a conditional variable is missing. I want a "0" in "Den" if any of the conditional variables has a "0". I only want a "1" in "Den"  if every conditional variable that is not missing has a value of "1". Does that help?

Comment: and what do you want if one is missing?

Comment: If all 3 conditional variables are missing values, only then would I want "Den" to be missing. But I want the value of "Den" to be based on the conditional variables with values that aren't missing (i.e. "0" or "1".  Your example above gives me a "0" when that condition should produce a "1" because the only conditional variable with a value ("Denial2") has a value of "1".

Comment: and it has to be in 1 statement?

Comment: No, I think I see what you're getting at, I can create the variable then use another conditional statement to to change it's value based on whether or not all three conditional variables are missing.

Comment: Something along those lines, yes.

Answer (score 4):

There is a simpler solution to this.  What you describe is the natural behavior of the `&` operator and can thus be done primitively:

```
> c(1,1,NA) & c(1,0,NA) & c(1,NA,NA)
[1]  TRUE FALSE    NA
```

If all are 1, then 1 is returned.  If any are 0, then 0.  If all are NA, then NA.

In your case, the code would be:

```
DF$Den<-DF$Denial1 & DF$Denial2 & DF$Denial3
```

In order for this to work, you will need to stop working in `character` and use `numeric` or `logical` types.

Comment: The OP's result provides a 1, while yours provides a NA.

Answer (score 4):

Very simple use of `any`

```
df <- <your structure>

df$Den <- apply(df,1,function(i) {ifelse(any(is.na(i)) | any(i != 1), 0, 1)})
```

Comment: Just wondering, how could we incorporate this using `dplyr::mutate`?

Comment: @HNSKD there I would use `dplyr::if_else`

Answer (score 3):

another solution using dplyr is:

```
df <- ## your data ##
df <- df %>%
        mutate(Den = ifelse(any(is.na(Den)) | any(Den != 1), 0, 1))
```