# New character values based on date range using ifelse

Tags: r, date, if-statement

I have some data with names I'm trying to rename based on certain date ranges. For now I don't have an end date, but in the future there will be so it would be nice to have both options. I'm fine converting date back to date if `ifelse()` coerces it into numeric format unless there is a better way. Do I just have to convert to numeric first and figure out which numbers correspond to my date range, run `ifelse()`, then convert back to date when done? I tried to get some insight from this but i'm not sure if it will work for me.  [Ifelse statement in R with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36362573/ifelse-statement-in-r-with-multiple-conditions)

```
structure(list(Serial = c("580300", "380201", "380201", "480862", 
"480862", "480862"), Name = c("Gomex", "Clammy", 
"Clammy", "Channel Islands", "Channel Islands", "Channel Islands"
), Date = structure(c(1476928800, 1553619600, 1476932400, 1503777600, 
1476936000, 1604070000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm trying to do something like this...

```
vue$Name <- ifelse(vue$Serial == "480862" & Date >= "2019-8-23 10:00:00", "newname", vue$Name)
```

```
Error in Date >= "2019-8-23 10:00:00" : 
  comparison (5) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your original error but I think you were missing some extraction operators `$` and inconsistent column names in your attempt `vue$name <- ifelse(vue$Serial == "480862" & vue$Date >= "2019-08-23 10:00:00", "newname", vue$Name)`

Comment: @EJJ You are correct, thanks for picking that up, i fixed the typos but the same error remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem `vue$Name <- ifelse(vue$Serial == "483689" && vue$Date >= "2019-8-23 10:00:00", "newname", vue$Name)`

I was missing the second `&` and `vue$` before `Date`