# Conditional if statement in R

Tags: r, apply

I would like to know how I can populate a column in a data.frame or data.table based on the value of other columns.

for example:

```
data.table(a = c(1:5), b = c(5:1), c = rep("",5))
 a b c
 1 5  
 2 4  
 3 3  
 4 2  
 5 1
```

I want to populate c to:

- indicate "More" if "a" is greater than "b"
- "Less" if "a" is less than "b"
- "Equal if they are equal

as below:

```
a b c
1 5 "Less" 
2 4 "Less" 
3 3 "Equal"
4 2 "More"
5 1 "More"
```

I know that this can be done through a for loop with multiple if statements, but I have a very large data set and I would like to do this using the "Apply" family of functions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested ifelse statement in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012222/nested-ifelse-statement-in-r)

Comment: Using `apply` would again invite for nested `ifelse`. Not sure if there is another way to use `apply` . `apply(df, 1, function(x) ifelse(x[1] > x[2], "More", ifelse(x[1] < x[2], "Less", "Equal")))`

Comment: The `apply` option mentioned above is not needed as it is a data.table.  Also, looping through rows and using `ifelse` is highly inefficient.  I already posted some efficient methods on my solution.

Comment: exactly. Just wanted to clarify why OP insisted on using `apply`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a numeric method to create unique values based on the logical vectors (`a > b` and `a==b`), convert to `factor`, get the `numeric` storage values by converting to `numeric`, replace that with the elements in the `vector` (`c("Less", "More", "Equal")`) and assign (`:=`) it as 'c'.

```
dt1[, c :=c("Less", "More", "Equal")[as.numeric(factor(1+2*(a>b) + 4*(a==b)))]]
dt1
#   a b     c
#1: 1 5  Less
#2: 2 4  Less
#3: 3 3 Equal
#4: 4 2  More
#5: 5 1  More
```

Or we can use a nested `ifelse` to get the expected output.

```
dt1[, c:= ifelse(a>b, "More", ifelse(a<b, "Less", "Equal"))]
```

Or another option would be using the `Reduce/max.col/pmax` to get a numeric index and replace it with the character vector as showed in the first method.

```
dt1[,  c:= c("Equal", "Less", "More")[pmax(max.col(.SD),
                         3*Reduce(`==`, .SD))], .SDcols = a:b]
```

#### data

```
dt1 <-  data.table(a = c(1:5), b = c(5:1), c = rep("",5))
```

Comment: Both methods worked like a charm in the given example. Though I think I prefer the second method to apply on my specific case as I find the first method a bit hard to understand.

Comment: can the first option be simplified to `dt1[, c := c("less","more","equal")[ (1 + (a >= b) + (a == b)) ] ]`?

Comment: @Symbolix Yes, It can be done, I thought by multiplying, we get the unique values.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one that seems bizarrely efficient by my testing, and is not overly complex:

```
dt1[, c := c("less","equal","more")[max.col(setDT(.(a < b, a==b, a > b)))] ]
```

Another option using `interaction` which is about as good as I can do in simplification of code:

```
dt1[, c := c("equal","less","more")[interaction(a < b, a > b)] ]

#   a b     c
#1: 1 5  less
#2: 2 4  less
#3: 3 3 equal
#4: 4 2  more
#5: 5 1  more
```

This works because `interaction` will return four possibilities for two comparisons:

1. `FALSE.FALSE` = neither `TRUE`, which in this case means not larger or smaller, therefore equal
2. `TRUE.FALSE` = first `TRUE`, therefore less
3. `FALSE.TRUE` = second `TRUE`, therefore more
4. `TRUE.TRUE`  = both `TRUE`, theoretically impossible except for fringe cases below the error tolerance.