# How to fill a new column using some specific conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, vlookup, cbind

[image: Table Details with new column position]

I have this table in which contain two columns (1st = names, 2nd =Positions*). I want add a 3rd column titled"GeneName" which should have the values according to $position column. As if the position value falls in any of the undermentioned class related GeneName should be written in the new column. 3 names to be filled in the new column are NIb, VPg and CI. 
Conditions are

```
NIb = from position 1014 to 2410
VPg = 3660 to 5563 and 
CI  = 5718 to 6282
```

Please see the image attached for better understanding.

Comment: Please add a better description to your image.

Comment: I cannot understand your table. What do you mean with level values according to the position column?

Comment: CI, Nib and VPg are the values to be entered in the new column according the numeric values of position colum. Please see the image attached.

Comment: Are there positions that don't fall in any of the three classes?

Comment: yes. There were but if-else statement worked just fine. I excluded those values which didn't fell in any category.

Answer (score 0):

I did this using ifelse statement multiple times.

```
fg$GeneName<-ifelse(fg$position_by_miRanda>=1014 & fg$position_by_miRanda<=2410,"NIb",fg$GeneName)

fg$GeneName<-ifelse(fg$position_by_miRanda>=3660 & fg$position_by_miRanda<=5563,"CI",fg$GeneName)

fg$GeneName<-ifelse(fg$position_by_miRanda>=5718 & fg$position_by_miRanda<=6282,"VPg",fg$GeneName)
```

Comment: You don't need to assign every condition separately. You can do a [nested ifelse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012222/nested-ifelse-statement-in-r)