# Nesting `if` statements in color parameter for `Rworldmaps`

Tags: r, if-statement, colors

I am trying to map geo-location data and corresponding scores using `rworldmaps`. There are three different types of scores, which I would like to represent with different colors. For instance there are positive scores (which I would like to mark with Green), negative scores (which I would like to mark with Red) and data where there was no score (which I would like to mark with yellow).
So far, I am able to correctly plot two scores (positive in green and negative in red), but I am having some difficulty with the third scored.

My code thus far is as follows:

```
data <- read.csv("/PATH/TO/CSV.csv",header=TRUE)
library(rworldmap)
newmap <- getMap(resolution="low")
plot(newmap,asp=1)
scores(data$Lat, data$Lon, col= ifelse(data[,3] > 0, 'green', 'red'),cex=.6)
```

The issue that I am having is in the last line of code beginning with `points`, I have tried to nest `if` statements, such as

```
scores(data$Lat, data$Lon, col= if(data[,3] > 0, 'green'), if(data[,3] < 0, 'red'), if(data[,3] = 0, 'yellow')),cex=.6)
```

as well as with nesting `ifelse` statements, as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012222/nested-ifelse-statement-in-r)

```
points(data$Lat, data$Lon, col= ifelse(data[,53] > 0, 'green', ifelse(data[,53]<0 'red', 'yellow')),cex=.6)
```

but I have been unsuccessful. Can anyone point me in the direction as to how to correctly nest the `if` statements, so that I can correctly color the map?
Thank you

Comment: It would be great if you can provide a subset of your `data` so it can be reproduced. Anyway, my guess is that the error comes at `col = ifelse(data[, 53] > 0, ...`. `data[, 53]` is an entire column of observations.

Comment: Here is the solution that seems to work: `points(data$Lat, data$Lon, col=ifelse(data[,53]> 0,"green" , ifelse(data[,53] < 0, "red", ifelse(data[,53]==0, "yellow", "unknown"))), cex=.6)`