# Creating a dummy variable in R using loan default data

Tags: r

I'm working with Lending Club data set and I'm trying to create a dummy variable for the target variable loan_status. So my main goal is for Charged Off to be 0 and Fully Paid to be 1 and all else would be 'NA'. The variable loan status has several values: Current, Fully Paid, Late, Grace Period, Delinquent, Charged off, and Does not qualify due to credit profile. I just want to focus on Charged Off and Fully Paid. I've tried numerous times but still no success. For example:

Creating a new target variable

```
loan_status1 <- if(loan_status== 'Fully Paid'){'Yes'} else if
 (loan_status== 'Charged Off') {'No'} else 'NA'
```

Also I've tried this:

```
if(loan_status=='Fully Paid'){
   0} else if (loan_status=='Charged Off') {
   1} else (loan_status=='NA')
```

I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: The most simple would be using vectorized `ifelse`, Try `loan_status1 <-ifelse(loan_status == 'Fully Paid', 1, ifelse(loan_status == 'Charged Off', 0, NA))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested ifelse statement in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012222/nested-ifelse-statement-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you could try to run a for-loop over your data by executing this:
Don't set NAs as strings ('NA'), better set to data type NA

```
loan_status <- sample(rep(c('Fully Paid', 'Charged Off', "abc"), 100), 100, replace = FALSE)

for (i in seq_along(loan_status)){
  if (loan_status[i] == 'Fully Paid'){
    loan_status[i] <- as.integer(0)
  } else if (loan_status[i] == 'Charged Off'){
    loan_status[i] <- as.integer(1)
  } else {
    loan_status[i] == NA
  }
}
```

Maybe you want to do this the easy way with the factor() function:

For instance you could do:

```
factor(loan_status, levels = c('Fully Paid', 'Charged Off'), labels = c(0, 1))
```

Comment: I would have upvoted your answer for the `factor` approach. But the `for` loop is a no go. It's a clumsy and slow re-implementation of [Ronak Shah's vectorized `ifelse` approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42967160/creating-a-dummy-variable-in-r-using-loan-default-data#comment73027898_42967160): `loan_status1 <- ifelse(loan_status == 'Fully Paid', 1, ifelse(loan_status == 'Charged Off', 0, NA))`

Comment: Oops, the for loop doesn't work at all. It returns "0"and "1" as character and leaves the "abc" unchanged. Reason: `loan_status[i] == NA` should read  `loan_status[i] <- NA`.

Answer (score 0):

The OP requested a 1:1 replacement, i.e., only one data field involved, of selected values. Besides the nested `ifelse` [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42967160/creating-a-dummy-variable-in-r-using-loan-default-data/42994206#comment73027898_42967160), this could be done by using factors or *join* for larger data.

If more than two or three values need to be replaced, the "hard-coded" nested `ifelse` approach easily gets unhandy.

#### Factor case 1: Yes, No

```
# create some data
loan_status <- c("Fully Paid", "Charged Off", "Something", "Else")
# do the conversion
factor(loan_status, levels = c("Fully Paid", "Charged Off"), labels = c("Yes", "No"))
#[1] Yes  No   <NA> <NA>
#Levels: Yes No
```

Or,

```
as.character(factor(loan_status, levels = c("Fully Paid", "Charged Off"), labels = c("Yes", "No")))
#[1] "Yes" "No"  NA    NA
```

if the result is expected as character.

#### Factor case 2: 0L, 1L as integers

If the result is expected to be of type integer, the factor approach can still be used but needs additonal conversion.

```
as.integer(as.character(factor(loan_status, levels = c("Fully Paid", "Charged Off"), labels = c("0", "1"))))
#[1]  0  1 NA NA
```

Note, that the conversion to character is essential here. Otherwise, the result would return the numbers of the factor levels:

```
as.integer(factor(loan_status, levels = c("Fully Paid", "Charged Off"), labels = c("0", "1")))
#[1]  1  2 NA NA
```

### Join

In case of larger data and many items to be replaced using `data.table` join might be an alternative worth considering:

```
library(data.table)
# create translation table
translation_map <- data.table(
  loan_status = c("Fully Paid", "Charged Off"),
  target = c(0L, 1L))
# create some user data
DT <- data.table(id = LETTERS[1:4],
                 loan_status = c("Fully Paid", "Charged Off", "Something", "Else"))
DT
#   id loan_status
#1:  A  Fully Paid
#2:  B Charged Off
#3:  C   Something
#4:  D        Else

# right join
translation_map[DT, on = "loan_status"]
#   loan_status target id
#1:  Fully Paid      0  A
#2: Charged Off      1  B
#3:   Something     NA  C
#4:        Else     NA  D
```

By default (`nomatch = NA`), `data.table` does a right join, i.e, takes all rows of `DT`.