# Trying to make variable from comparing 2 others

Tags: r, if-statement

I am using the `home_goal` and `away_goal` to make a new variable to see the game result for the game.

This is what I have

```
 if(data$home_team_goal < data$away_team_goal){
  data$result <- c('H')
}else if (data$home_team_goal > data$away_team_goal){
  data$result<- c('A')
}else (data$home_team_goal ==  data$away_team_goal){
  data$result<- c('D')
}
```

it giving all the game a draw.

Comment: Using `if` in that way doesn't vectorise over the rows. Do you not get a warning about 'only the first element being used'? It's probably taking the results of the first row and just copying that everywhere else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested ifelse statement in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012222/nested-ifelse-statement-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
    mutate(result = case_when(home_team_goal == away_team_goal~"D", 
                              home_team_goal >  away_team_goal ~ "H", 
                              TRUE ~ "A"))
#    home_team_goal away_team_goal result
#1              0              1      A
#2              0              0      D
#3              2              4      A
#4              3              1      H
#5              3              4      A
#6              1              1      D
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a couple of `ifelse` statements. And I'd use the `dplyr` package, then you can just refer to the columns by name instead of the verbose `$` syntax, and add the new column using `mutate`. Also, `data` is not a great name for a data frame, so I'm using `data1`.

```
install.packages("dplyr") # if required
library(dplyr)

data1 <- data.frame(home_team_goal = c(0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 1),
                    away_team_goal = c(1, 0, 4, 1, 4, 1))

data1 %>% 
  mutate(result = ifelse(home_team_goal == away_team_goal, "D", 
                  ifelse(home_team_goal >  away_team_goal, "H", "A")))


  home_team_goal away_team_goal result
1              0              1      A
2              0              0      D
3              2              4      A
4              3              1      H
5              3              4      A
6              1              1      D
```

Comment: Why not use `if_else` if using dplyr? It's quicker I believe.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you're just wanting a label for the difference between the two columns being `>0`, `0` or `<0`. It is only one comparison and there is no need for looping over multiple `if/else`, `ifelse` or `case_when`:

```
factor(with(data1, sign(home_team_goal - away_team_goal)), labels=c("A","D","H"))
#[1] A D A H A D
#Levels: A D H
```

If you don't want the `factor` output:

```
c("A","D","H")[factor(with(data1, sign(home_team_goal - away_team_goal)))]
#[1] "A" "D" "A" "H" "A" "D"
```