# If else condition to replace column values in R

Tags: r

I am trying to replace column values of `df$status`. The conditions are, any values that is 1 takes "CO", 2 takes "CA", 3 takes "MCI" and anything else takes "unknown". I tried this code below, but it is not giving me the expected result. What do I need to do with this if else condition here?

```
if (df$STATUS==1){
  df$STATUS <- "CO"
} else if (df$STATUS==2) {
  df$STATUS  <- "CA"
} else if (df$STATUS==3) {
  df$STATUS  <- "MCI"
} else {
  df$STATUS  <- "unknown"
}
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(FID = structure(c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 1L, `3` = 1L, 
`4` = 1L, `5` = 1L, `6` = 1L), .Label = "0", class = "factor"), 
    IID = structure(1:6, .Names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
    "6"), .Label = c("07AD5724", "08AD10457", "08AD10956", "08AD10987", 
    "08AD11073", "08AD11218"), class = "factor"), COHORT = structure(c(`1` = 1L, 
    `2` = 1L, `3` = 1L, `4` = 1L, `5` = 1L, `6` = 1L), .Label = "CHOP_AA", class = "factor"), 
    SEX = structure(c(`1` = 3L, `2` = 2L, `3` = 3L, `4` = 1L, 
    `5` = 1L, `6` = 2L), .Label = c(" 1", " 2", "-9"), class = "factor"), 
    PC1 = structure(c(`1` = 5L, `2` = 1L, `3` = 6L, `4` = 2L, 
    `5` = 3L, `6` = 4L), .Label = c(" 0.0007", "-0.0054", "-0.0106", 
    "-0.0224", "-0.1090", "-9.0000"), class = "factor"), PC2 = structure(c(`1` = 1L, 
    `2` = 3L, `3` = 6L, `4` = 2L, `5` = 4L, `6` = 5L), .Label = c(" 0.0041", 
    " 0.0130", " 0.0161", "-0.0004", "-0.0164", "-9.0000"), class = "factor"), 
    PC3 = structure(c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 4L, `3` = 6L, `4` = 3L, 
    `5` = 2L, `6` = 5L), .Label = c(" 0.0073", " 0.0091", " 0.0145", 
    "-0.0104", "-0.0214", "-9.0000"), class = "factor"), STATUS = structure(c(`1` = 2L, 
    `2` = 1L, `3` = 3L, `4` = 1L, `5` = 1L, `6` = 2L), .Label = c(" 1", 
    " 2", "-9"), class = "factor"), PC4 = structure(c(`1` = 3L, 
    `2` = 2L, `3` = 6L, `4` = 4L, `5` = 1L, `6` = 5L), .Label = c(" 0.0073", 
    " 0.0431", "-0.0102", "-0.0210", "-0.0498", "-9.0000"), class = "factor"), 
    PC5 = structure(c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 5L, `3` = 6L, `4` = 2L, 
    `5` = 3L, `6` = 4L), .Label = c(" 0.0081", " 0.0123", "-0.0029", 
    "-0.0327", "-0.0350", "-9.0000"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Use `ifelse` or `dplyr::case_when`.

Comment: @RonakShah I thought `ifelse` replaces only two condictions.

Comment: `ifelse` can be nested, e.g., `ifelse(x == 1, "x is 1", ifelse(x == 2, "x is 2", "x is not 1 or 2"))`. There's a nice detailed explanation and example at the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18016872/903061) of the first flagged duplicate question - have a look! However, for more than 2 conditions `dplyr::case_when` is cleaner. There are examples at both marked duplicates.