# If...else error 'the condition has lenght >1...' with multiple operations at each statement

Tags: r

I have a series of `if` statements in a function. It looks like this:

```
my_func <- function(data, selection) {

 if (selection == 'p+c') {
 predictors = 'chicago'
 preds <- data
}
else if (selection== 'p') { 
  predictors = 'new_york'
  preds <- data %>% dplyr::select(-c(region, sale))
}
else if (selection == 'c') {
  predictors = 'california'
  preds <- data %>% dplyr::select(region, sale)
} 
# then the function does something else with predictors and preds, 
#  and returns a dataframe  
}

my_func(my_data, selection = 'p')
```

I keep getting the warning that `the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`. Weirdly, it doesn't actually break anything (it all works as expected), but I still would rather amend this problem.

I read that this is a problem with vectorization, but I don't know how to overcome this.

I already tried replacing the if/else with `ifelse` (as suggested in other posts) but this did not work, maybe because I do more than one operation at each `if` statement. I did this:

```
 ifelse (selection == 'p+c') {
 predictors = 'chicago'
 preds <- data
}
ifelse (selection== 'p') { 
  predictors = 'new_york'
  preds <- data %>% dplyr::select(-c(region, sale))
}
ifelse (selection == 'c') {
  predictors = 'california'
  preds <- data %>% dplyr::select(region, sale)
}
```

Comment: "I already tried replacing the if/else with ifelse (as suggested in other posts) but this did not work" -- show what you tried. It is non-problematic to have nested calls to `ifelse`.

Comment: Hi @JohnColeman I just amended the post to show it, thank you for your comment

Comment: You aren't using `ifelse` as a *function* at all. If you are familiar with Excel, `ifelse` works like Excel's `IF` function.

Comment: Sorry @JohnColeman, I'm not sure I know how else to do this

Comment: did you go over the documentation for `ifelse()`? maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012222/nested-ifelse-statement

Comment: This means that `selection` has more than 1 value in it like `c('p+c', 'p')`. What would be output in such case?

Comment: What does `selection` contain?

Comment: Hi @rbasa, sorry I didn't specify the details. I amended the post now. 'selection' is one of the arguments of a function that the if/else statements are in.

Comment: Hi @RonakShah, yes `selection` can have three values. It is an argument in the function, my edits (hopefully) reflect this now. Thank you

Comment: Your code is still not reproducible or clear to me. So `selection` can have 3 values but what is the expected output in that case? Consider adding an example dummy dataframe and show us the expected output for it. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Also if you are running `my_func(my_data, selection = 'p')` this should not give you the warning since `selection` is only `p` here which is of length 1 and not length > 1 (as mentioned in the warning). Maybe the warning is coming from somehwere else in the code that you have not shown.

Comment: @RonakShah yep, it was something else in the code. I noticed I was over-writing the `selection`, and it added more elements to it. Thank you so much for pointing this out.

Comment: `the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used` will only show up if `selection` contains more than 1 element.

Answer (score 1):

`ifelse` is a function, you need to assign the results of it to your variables (rather than placing the assignments inside the function call itself). Without a reproducible example (which you neglected to provide -- see [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4996248)) it is hard to be sure that the following code does exactly what you want, but something like:

```
predictors <- ifelse(selection == 'p+c',
    'chicago',
     ifelse(selection == 'p',
         'new york',
          ifelse(selection == 'c',
              'california',
              'NA')))
```

(with similar code for `preds`).

Comment: Thank you. Do I have to run this two times then, one time with the names (e.g. 'chicago') and one time to change the data (i.e. for `preds`)?

Answer (score 1):

You have two questions here.  The message

> the condition has length > 1...

arises because `if()` is not vectorised.  I assume *selection* has more than one value.

`ifelse` are most useful when you have exactly two options.  For multiple options, a decent option is nested `else if()` statements:

Without the data, I can't check this, a nested `else if` solution would be:

```
 if (selection == 'p+c') {
   predictors = 'chicago'
   preds <- data
 } else if(selection == 'p') { 
   predictors = 'new_york'
   preds <- data %>% dplyr::select(-c(region, sale))
 } else if (selection == 'c') {
   predictors = 'california'
   preds <- data %>% dplyr::select(region, sale)
 } else { # Good practice to capture errors safely
   stop("Selection not found")
 }
```

If you need to keep *selection* as a vector, e.g. `selection <- c("p+c", "c")` then you make the above statement into a function and pass it to an 'apply()' statement, e.g.

```
checkFunction <- function(selection) {
    if(selection == 'p+c') {
      predictors = 'chicago'
      preds <- data
    } else if(selection == 'p') { 
      predictors = 'new_york'
      preds <- data %>% dplyr::select(-c(region, sale))
    } else if (selection == 'c') {
      predictors = 'california'
      preds <- data %>% dplyr::select(region, sale)
    } else { # Good practice to capture errors safely
      stop("Selection not found")
    }
  
  return(list(predictors, preds))
}
   
output <- sapply(selection, checkFunction)

 > output
     p+c       c        
[1,] "chicago" "california
[2,] tbl_df,3  tbl_df,2
```

`output[,1]`

```
[[1]]
[1] "chicago"

[[2]]
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  region  sale other
   <int> <int> <int>
1      1     2     3
2      2     3     4
3      3     4     5
4      4     5     6
5      5     6     7
```