# R programming, Ifelse Error: "Error in ifelse(i %in% c(1, 6), rasterImage(ringIMG2, -22, -22, 22, 22, : replacement has length zero: "

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, nested-for-loop

I am trying to run different versions of the same command in a for loop based on the value of i.

If i equals 1 or 6 run this:
rasterImage(ringIMG2, -22, -22, 22, 22, interpolate=FALSE, angle =0)

If i equals 2, 3 or 5 run this:
rasterImage(ringIMG2, -22, -22, 22, 22, interpolate=FALSE, angle =0)

If i equals 4 run this:
rasterImage(ringIMG2, -23.5, -23.5, 23.5, 23.5, interpolate=FALSE, angle =0)

I am using a nested ifelse statement.

```
  for (i in 1:6)
  {
    #adjusts size of image within the plot
    ifelse(i %in% c(1,6), rasterImage(ringIMG2, -22, -22, 22, 22, interpolate=FALSE, angle =0),
           ifelse(i %in% c(2,3,5), rasterImage(ringIMG2, -23, -23, 23, 23, interpolate=FALSE, angle =0),
                  rasterImage(ringIMG2, -23.5, -23.5, 23.5, 23.5, interpolate=FALSE, angle =0)
           )
    )
    }
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in ifelse(i %in% c(1, 6), rasterImage(ringIMG2, -22, -22, 22, 22,  : 
  replacement has length zero
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In readPNG(paste0("R", i, ".png")) :
  libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
2: In rep(yes, length.out = length(ans)) :
  'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL
```

The code on its own is running fine:

```
rasterImage(ringIMG2, -22, -22, 22, 22, interpolate=FALSE, angle =0)
```

Well I'm still getting the first warning but that is not any real concern.

I have tried the simplifying and it seems to work...

```
check <- ifelse(i %in% c(1,6), print('Yes'))
[1] "Yes"
```

My syntax looks ok based on the link below:

[Nested ifelse syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012222/nested-ifelse-statement)

```
ifelse(<condition>, <yes>,  
              ifelse(<condition>, <yes>, <no>)
                    )
       )
```

Anyone got an idea where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `if` and `else` — not to be confused with `ifelse()`.

`ifelse()` is useful when you want to create a vector of values based on a vector of conditions. It returns a vector the same length as the test condition, and expects all arguments to be the same length. But `rasterImage()` doesn’t have a return value — passing it as an argument to `ifelse()` is equivalent to passing `NULL`. `length(i) != length(NULL)`, so you get an error.

But `if` and `else` are standard control flow statements, rather than functions with prescribed inputs and outputs, so will work better for your case:

```
for (i in 1:6) {
  if (i %in% c(1,6)) {
    rasterImage(ringIMG2, -22, -22, 22, 22, interpolate=FALSE, angle =0)
  } else if (i %in% c(2,3,5)) {
    rasterImage(ringIMG2, -23, -23, 23, 23, interpolate=FALSE, angle =0)
  } else {
    rasterImage(ringIMG2, -23.5, -23.5, 23.5, 23.5, interpolate=FALSE, angle =0)
  }
}
```

You could also accomplish this a bit more concisely without `if` statements:

```
for (i in c(22, 23, 23, 23.5, 23, 22)) {
  rasterImage(ringIMG2, -i, -i, i, i, interpolate=FALSE, angle =0)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and simplified code suggestions. Much appreciated :)