# How to add if-then-else conditions in a select query?

Tags: sql, plsql

I would like to apply the following conditions in a `select query`.

```
IF  (TYPE = MBUSA or SDSA or MDSA OR PC) and (FINAL_STATUS = ACTIVE OR EXECUTED) 
then GET ID and Parent_ID
ELSEIF (TYPE = MSA) and (FINAL_STATUS = ACTIVE OR EXECUTED)
then  GET ID---(USING the ID from the else if condition AS FILTER, 
IF TYPE = (DSA OR BUSA) AND (FINAL_STATUS = ACTIVE OR EXECUTED) 
then GET ID and Parent_ID)
```

Do I need to write a procedure?

**Following is the database structure:**

[image: http://i.imgur.com/L1VqOE3.png]

Comment: Can you provide your table structure, some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: Hi Mureinik, I uploaded the example screenshot, Please check and help me....Thanks again! FYI Completed = Executed.

Answer (score 5):

The `CASE` statement can be used as an equivalent of an `IF.. THEN... ELSE...` statement. Not quite sure how you are wanting to select them as your question is unclear so here's a couple of suggestions.

To select a single column with a string representation of the conditional formatting:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN (TYPE IN ('MBUSA','SDSA','MDSA','PC') AND (FINAL_STATUS IN ('ACTIVE','EXECUTED')) 
            THEN ID + ' ' + P_ID
        WHEN ((TYPE = 'MSA') AND (FINAL_STATUS IN ('ACTIVE','EXECUTED'))
            THEN ID
        WHEN (TYPE IN ('DSA','BUSA') AND (FINAL_STATUS IN ('ACTIVE','EXECUTED')) 
            THEN ID + ' ' + P_ID
        ELSE ''
    END AS columnName
FROM
    tableName
```

To select each into separate columns

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN (TYPE IN ('MBUSA','SDSA','MDSA','PC') AND (FINAL_STATUS IN ('ACTIVE','EXECUTED')) 
            THEN ID
        WHEN ((TYPE = 'MSA') AND (FINAL_STATUS IN ('ACTIVE','EXECUTED'))
            THEN ID
        WHEN (TYPE IN ('DSA','BUSA') AND (FINAL_STATUS IN ('ACTIVE','EXECUTED')) 
            THEN ID
        ELSE ''
    END AS columnOneName
    CASE
        WHEN (TYPE IN ('MBUSA','SDSA','MDSA','PC') AND (FINAL_STATUS IN ('ACTIVE','EXECUTED')) 
            THEN P_ID
        WHEN ((TYPE = 'MSA') AND (FINAL_STATUS IN ('ACTIVE','EXECUTED'))
            THEN NULL
        WHEN (TYPE IN ('DSA','BUSA') AND (FINAL_STATUS IN ('ACTIVE','EXECUTED')) 
            THEN  P_ID
        ELSE ''
    END AS columnTwoName
FROM
    tableName
```

Though looking at the above (I've probably transcribed your logic incorrectly) there are three case statements when you could get away with 2:

```
CASE
    WHEN (TYPE IN ('MBUSA','SDSA','MDSA','PC','DSA','BUSA') AND (FINAL_STATUS IN ('ACTIVE','EXECUTED')) 
        THEN ID + ' ' + P_ID
    WHEN ((TYPE = 'MSA') AND (FINAL_STATUS IN ('ACTIVE','EXECUTED'))
        THEN ID
    ELSE ''
END AS columnName
```

I know you've put a screenshot up now, but an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) would probably be more helpful or more detail so that table names etc. can be easily

Useful Links:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

[SQL Case Statement Syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622/sql-case-statement-syntax)

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/14/sql-server-case-statementexpression-examples-and-explanation/

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE to implement IF-THEN-ELSE in PL/SQL - this is just an example:

```
    select case field1 WHEN '1' THEN 'VALUE1'
                       WHEN '2' THEN 'VALUE2'
                       ELSE 'VALUEOTHER'
                       END,
           case field2 WHEN '1' THEN 'VALUE1'
                       WHEN '2' THEN 'VALUE2'
                       ELSE 'VALUEOTHER'
                       END                  
    from (                   

    select '1' "FIELD1",
           '2' "FIELD2"
    from dual
    );
```

You cannot use the CASE statement on multiple columns; however, if you need to compare 
multiple fields in the same CASE statement, you could use a workaround like this:

```
    select case field1 || '_' || field2
                       WHEN '1_1' THEN 'FIELD1-IS-VALUE1 AND FIELD2-IS-VALUE1'
                       WHEN '1_2' THEN 'FIELD1-IS-VALUE1 AND FIELD2-IS-VALUE2'
                       WHEN '2_1' THEN 'FIELD1-IS-VALUE2 AND FIELD2-IS-VALUE1'
                       WHEN '2_2' THEN 'FIELD1-IS-VALUE2 AND FIELD2-IS-VALUE2'
                       ELSE 'VALUEOTHER'
                       END
    from (                   

    select '1' "FIELD1",
           '2' "FIELD2"
    from dual
    );
```

If the SQL statement becomes difficult to read it may be better to use views with the SQL statement or use PL/SQL.

References:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18239/using-same-case-when-conditions-for-multiple-query-columns