# Getting Employee Details and Gender

Tags: sql, case

```
select employees.emp_no, employees.birth_date, employees.first_name, employees.last_name,
case 
when dept_manager.emp_no IS NOT NULL THEN 'Manager' ELSE 'Employee' END AS Is_Manager
from employees
WHEN employees.gender = 'M' THEN 'Male' ELSE 'Female' END AS 'Gender' 
LEFT JOIN 
dept_manager ON  dept_manager.emp_no = employees.emp_no;
```

I wanted to get employees with their gender and whether manager or not. I thought I could use CASE with two conditions. On introducing the second condition I got an EOF error. Kindly help check what could be wrong with my code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a tag for your DBMS and include the error message in full.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
select employees.emp_no, employees.birth_date, employees.first_name, employees.last_name,
(case when dept_manager.emp_no IS NOT NULL THEN 'Manager' 
ELSE 'Employee' END)Is_Manager
(case when employees.gender = 'M' THEN 'Male' ELSE 'Female' END)Gender 
from employees
LEFT JOIN 
dept_manager ON  dept_manager.emp_no = employees.emp_no;
```

Answer (score 0):

The query is syntactically wrong.

- `FROM` clause needs to go after all the list of columns in `SELECT` clause.
- When you added the second condition for a new column `Gender`, you also needed to write the keyword `CASE` before the `WHEN` condition.

Below is the correct syntax:

```
SELECT employees.emp_no, employees.birth_date, employees.first_name, employees.last_name,
CASE WHEN dept_manager.emp_no IS NOT NULL THEN 'Manager' ELSE 'Employee' END AS Is_Manager,
CASE WHEN employees.gender = 'M' THEN 'Male' ELSE 'Female' END AS Gender
FROM employees
LEFT JOIN 
dept_manager ON  dept_manager.emp_no = employees.emp_no;
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4626/5079776) is an answer on how to use the CASE syntax in SQL.